# php curl login problem

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
// create a new CURL resource
$file_path = '/mail';
define("COOKIE_FILE", "c:\cookie.txt");
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mail.gov.in/iwc/signin");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
session_write_close();
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=d095af0e30afc021dd3652734009' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/mail';
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'fromLogin=true&domainName=nic.in&username=&password=&button=Sign%20In');

$url = curl_getinfo($ch);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data."<pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($url);

// close CURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

whats wrong with my code why i am not able to login directly in their mail

Comment: For example take some time to write a proper question with normal sentences and grammar. At least, if you expect any help.

Comment: And please don't post duplicates. What the hell. You asked the same question a few hours ago. -1, voting to close.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757442/php-curl-login-problem

Comment: i dint get the required answer so i have posted

Comment: @user You're showing no respect for people's time. You have received a high-quality answer in your other question. Put in some effort there. And please refrain from posting duplicates in the future.

Comment: Listen to what Pekka have said. **do not use curl**. Use **IMAP** functions. Do you understand english?

Comment: my requirement is using curl and not imap functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a hard-coding a session ID, then loading the COOKIE_FILE. Make sure that there's not another PHPSESSID cookie in the cookie file already. It may be overriding the session ID you just set manually.

As well, you're passing in username and password keys in the POST data, but not actually sending the username and password. Maybe you've censored them from this post, but it's worth pointing out. It should most likely be "....&username=SOMEUSER&password=SOMEPASSWORD".

You then do a `curl_getinfo()`, but you have not yet done the `curl_exec()` call, so there's nothing available to get information on, other than some CURL internal settings.

You may want to check if `$data` is FALSE before outputting it, in case that something failed within CURL:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
if ($data === FALSE) {
    print("CURL failed: " . curl_error($ch) . "\n");
}
var_dump($info); // print out full information array from curl
var_dump($data); // print out anything the server may have returned
```

Comment: Server Error
This server has encountered an internal error which prevents it from fulfilling your request. The most likely cause is a misconfiguration. Please ask the administrator to look for messages in the server's error log. "

Comment: array(20) { ["url"]=>  string(30) "https://mail.nic.in/mail/mauth" ["content_type"]=>  string(9) "text/html" ["http_code"]=>  int(500) ["header_size"]=>  int(244) ["request_size"]=>  int(412) ["filetime"]=>  int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=>  int(20) ["redirect_count"]=>  int(0) ["total_time"]=>  float(0.031) ["namelookup_time"]=>  float(0) ["connect_time"]=>  float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=>  float(0.031) ["size_upload"]=>  float(92) ["size_download"]=>  float(305) ["speed_download"]=>  float(9838) ["speed_upload"]=>  float(2967) ["download_content_length"]=>

Comment: @user `Please ask the administrator to look for messages in the server's error log`

Comment: The remote server is returning error code 500 - 'Internal Server Error'. Unless there's something about your POST request that's causing the problem (malformed request breaking their script or something), the error is occuring on the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to screen scrape a webmail inbox. To get help with that, you need to provide much more info.

However, PHP offers the possibility to access POP3 mailboxes directly: [IMAP Functions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) In the user contributed notes, there is what seems to be [a full-fledged code snippet](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php#96414) to access POP3 mailboxes.

Answer (score 2):

use curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie ) for cookie in http header & edit your code to get $strCookie value, this phpsession id value would be invalid..

```
1. $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=d095af0e30afc021dd3652734009' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/mail';
```

u can rewrite ur strcookie like this

```
2. $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/mail';
```

Or u can use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE & CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR to save cookie on file (without CURLOPT_COOKIE)

```
if(!file_exists(COOKIE_FILE)) {
    $fh = fopen(COOKIE_FILE, "w");
    fwrite($fh,"");
    fclose($fh); 
} 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
```

Hope this helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the referer gets checked, CURLOPT_REFERER.

Answer (score 0):

check `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`: where's the login passw and username?
You set `CURLOPT_COOKIE` which includes the cookie you gave, but `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);`  does the same thing.